# How to find xml tags in string content?

Tags: java, xml

I have a `String` content that comes from any soap `XML` request.

I want to I identify a specific tag `<FieldName>` having the value `MyFieldIndicator`, and from there fetch the value of the next occuring `<FieldValue>`.

How could I do this? Is there any library? Or which mechanisms could be used to extract those tags from a plain string?

Performance matters, so it should be as quick as possible.

Comment: You can do that with XPath. Give it a shot. Examples on how to use XPath in Java are all over the internet; when you have tried and it did not work and there is some actual code to show, post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the library dom4j is probably easiest to use and understand. You need to create a  [Document-Object from string](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/faq.html#from-string) and then access via iterators the tags. The documentation and examples can be fopund [here](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/guide.html)

Generally u can probably use any DOM or SAX parser.

Other DOM parser : W3C, JDOM

SAX parser : JAXP

If u by any chance want to store the content into an object : try to learn [JAXB](https://jaxb.java.net/)